# CSS margin being ignored on a column

Tags: html, css

I have a 3 column layout which is successfully giving me 3 columns; however, my third column (similar to my first column) needs margin and padding changes. Unfortunately, I seem unable to adjust margin and padding for that column. I'm not really sure the issue and googling is bringing me no answers.

CSS:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: #ecf0f1;
    color: #2c3e50;
    font-family: "Georgia", serif;
}

h1, h2 {
    font-family: "Franklin Gothic", sans-serif;
}

.header h1 {
    background: #2c3e50;
    color:#ecf0f1;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 25px 15px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 0px rgba(136,136,136,1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 0px rgba(136,136,136,1);
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 0px rgba(136,136,136,1);
}

.row {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 0;
}

.row div {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.col-3 {
    width: 25%;
    display: inline-block;

}

.col-6 {
    width: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
}

.menu {
    float: left;
}

.menu ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 10px 0px;
    padding: 0;
}

.menu li {
    background: #2980b9;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #ecf0f1;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 5px 25px;
    font-family: "Franklin Gothic", sans-serif;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 0px rgba(136,136,136,1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 0px rgba(136,136,136,1);
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 0px rgba(136,136,136,1);
}

.right {
  float:right;
}

.right p {
  margin: 10px;
}

.aside {
    text-align: center;
    background: #2980b9;
  height: 390px;
    color: #ecf0f1;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 0px rgba(136,136,136,1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 0px rgba(136,136,136,1);
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 0px rgba(136,136,136,1);

  /* THESE DO NOT WORK AND I CAN'T FIGURE OUT WHY */
  margin: 25px;
  padding: 25px;
}

.footer {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}

.footer p {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 0px rgba(136,136,136,1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 0px rgba(136,136,136,1);
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 0px rgba(136,136,136,1);
    padding: 50px 0px;
    background: #2980b9;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ecf0f1;
    margin: 10px 10px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>

    <meta chrset="utf-8" />
    <title>CMST-290 Project 2</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>
<body>

<div class="header">

    <h1>Jacob Johnson</h1>

</div>

<div class="row">

    <div class="col-3 menu">

        <ul>
            <li>Education</li>
            <li>Software</li>
            <li>Skills</li>
            <li>Awards</li>
            <li>Experience</li>
            <li>Projects</li>
        </ul>

    </div>

    <div class="col-6">

        <h1>Career Objective</h1>
        <p>
        I want to ensure quality in everything I do. I will work hard to achieve the goals my employer has for as well the goals I have set for myself.
        </p>

    </div>

    <div class="col-3 right">
        <div class="aside">

            <h2>Developer</h2>
            <p>I am familiar with front end tools such as HTML/CSS and JavaScript in addition to languages like C#, Python, and Java.</p>

            <h2>Designer</h2>
            <p>I have designed several websites from scratch.</p>

            <h2>Student</h2>
            <p>I am always eager to learn and keep improving my skills.</p>

        </div>
    </div>

</div>

<div class="footer">
    <p>Copyright &copy; 2017 | Jacob B. Johnson</p>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript" src="/d2l/common/math/MathML.js?v=10.6.10.5455-164 "></script>
<script type="text/javascript">document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() { D2LMathML.DesktopInit('https://s.brightspace.com/lib/mathjax/2.6.1/MathJax.js?config=MML_HTMLorMML','https://s.brightspace.com/lib/mathjax/2.6.1/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML'); });</script>

</body>
</html>
```

[CodePen link](http://codepen.io/jacob_johnson/pen/jBmoKe?editors=1100)

Any insight would be awesome as to why I was so easily able to adjust the left-most column but not the right-most. Thanks.

Comment: What do you actually want to achieve ?

Comment: Can you add your HTML code?

Comment: added the HTML. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your styles on `aside` are being ignored because the `.row div` selector is *more specific*, and therefore overriding `margin` and `padding` to zero.

Adding this should make it work:

```
.right .aside {
  margin: 25px;
  padding: 25px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need higher specificity because you've used `.row div` with `margin: 0; padding: 0;`. So to override that CSS with a margin or padding change, you will need to use `.row` in front of a selector like `.col-3`, so that the rule is `.row .col-3 { /* margin/padding *}`

You can read more about specificity here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity